# Best option to have a holding page while developing

Tags: htaccess

I am working on a new Magento site and have a "coming soon page" running (`HTML/CSS/JS`). This conflicts with the Magento setup and therefore it doesn't show (due to `.htaccess` redirecting everything to `index.php`).

My question is: What is the best way to keep the coming page running but being able to work with the backend?

Any suggestion is welcome, if possible please provide guide or link to a tutorial.

Comment: WE are trying to put Html page to our website http://www.printingstudio.in. Its not showing up as its conflicting wit installed magento index.php file. plz help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd simply create a subdomain eg (dev.mydomain.com) which directs to a different folder on your hosting (eg: dev) and develop on there?

When you're ready to go live, edit the db core_config_data 'web/unsecure/base_url' and 'web/secure/base_url' values, delete or rename the var/cache folder and rename the directory (eg: dev => live) or to whatever the folder is called that your www. domain points to.

Log in your backend and clear the cache and check it's all working.

Done

Comment: Just did this, works perfectly, quick note for others that are going to do this, use dynamic links and not static as you have to change it all back when you go live :)

Answer (score 5):

Another solution to work while your site is under maintenance is:

- add a file to your root maintenance.flag
- add to your index this lines:

  after this

  **$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';**

  add this

> ```
> $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
> $allowed = array('127.0.0.1','Another IP'); // these are the IP's that are allowed to view the site
>
> if ((file_exists($maintenanceFile)) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
>     include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
>     exit;
>  }
> ```

So you can edit your errors/503.php to whatever you want or put your own file.
And anyone that is in the allowed IP's could see the site and everyone else will see the 503 file.

Comment: This one did not work for me, it loads the home page of Magento instead of the coming soon page.

Comment: @ZakLewis If you have a file "maintenance.flag" in your root and you have your IP in the $allowed IP's then you should see your website. But the rest of IP's should not.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this for maintenance mode forever http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/maintenance-page-artson-it.html

You can set development IP's so you can view front and backend yourself.

You can customize the maintenance page easily from admin