# Magento in subfolder. Error in category page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a magento installation "live" in my server ( www.mydomain.com ) and moved another installation of magento ( test website ) in a subfolder ( www.mydomain.com/test ). When i try to open the subfolder, i see only the homepage, and if i try to open category page , i see "page not found" but with graphic of live website. How i can fix this problem? I tryed to move the index.php and .htaccess of live website to website in test folder , and magento show me the homepage, but other page not work. I use magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 2):

In your /subfolder install, make sure you have the correct settings in your htaccess file:

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /subfolder/
```

I also hope you aren't running these 2 stores from the same db tables, because your 'base_url' settings in core_config_data will be wrong for one of them at least.

Comment: Thanks i solve now, but the admin path not work. About DB I use 2 different DB :)

Comment: Maybe you should set up a subdomain for your testing install to avoid conflics: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55719/best-option-to-have-a-holding-page-while-developing/55722#55722