# Moving Magento installation from localhost to sub-directory in server root?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, localhost

The title says it all .. however I'm having a problem.

I transferred my installation from localhost to a sub-directory in the server root name `test`.

I edited `app/etc/local.xml` to include the correct credentials as well as updating base URL within the `core_config_data` table.

When going to the url **http://mydomain/test** all I get is a blank page. Of course the admin doesn't work either. When I put the Magento installation in the server root it works fine but not in a sub-directory.

Does anyone have a clue as to why this happens?

If you need any more info please let me know. I'm using Magento CE 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rewrite directives (SEO URLS) you need to edit your htaccess and change the RewriteBase to

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /test/
```

Then manually rename the 'var/cache' folder and make sure it gets recreated when you try and reload the index.php

---

Edit:

here is a smple local.xml file

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Wed, 11 Feb 2015 12:25:38 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[bf0accb767a157c6da44eca568a92142]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[root]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[local_magento_com]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>    
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Comment: I removed the `#` (which I assume is a comment) and edited the value just like you did but it did not work. I also rename the cache folder and it still does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, the # means that line was commented out. Did the cache folder get recreated?

Comment: It did not, but how would I make sure it does? I'm still seeing the same blank page when going to `http://mydomain/test/` or `http://mydomain/test/index.php` - this seems like it should be a lot easier :/

Comment: Check the folder permissions - specifically of `var` - the server should be able to create a directory in there. That may be the issue.

Comment: Nope, it's permissions are 755 which I assume is ok. I renamed the cache folder to `c` and keep reloading the URL but nothing is being created :/

Comment: That is strange - so db connection is correct in local.xml - core_config_data URLs are correct - permissions are correct - rewrite base is set .... I can't think of anything else =(

Comment: The only thing that may be wrong is the `<host`> node within local.xml -- should this also be `http://mydomain/test` or something else? I wasn't sure what to put there.

Comment: I don't have any <host> iwthin any of my local.xml files. `<config><global>` and within I have `<install>`, `<crypt>`, `<disable_local_modules>`, `<resources>` for the db connection settings and `<session_save>` that's all in `<global>`- then lastly '<admin>' for the path to the admin backend. I'll update my answer with a sample local.xml

Comment: What's weird is I have another file within my magento root folder called `index.html` and when I go to that it works. It's just when I try to access `index.php` that I get the blank page. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas on this. Sorry. I usually configure subdomains for testing / developing and I have never had to move an install into a subfolder. See here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55719/best-option-to-have-a-holding-page-while-developing/55722#55722