# Adding a "fake" subfolder in base url

Tags: multistore, base-url

About the "off topic" flag : This is **not** offtopic. As you can see in the accepted answer, it was about Magento config (db + htaccess)

For corporate / political reasons, we are trying to add a fake subfolder to our base urls. I can't configure vhosts/base urls to make it work with this additional string (404 for any page but home page)

Before :
subdomain1.company.com -> store 1
subdomain2.company.com -> store 2

After (help ?) :
subdomain1.company.com/corporate/ -> store 1
subdomain2.company.com/corporate/ -> store 2

I've set each vhost like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/root/directory"
    ServerName subdomain1.company.com
    Alias /corporate "/path/to/root/directory"
    <Directory /path/to/root/directory>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine On
        Options +FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>

    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE store1
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/root/directory"
    ServerName subdomain2.company.com
    Alias /corporate "/path/to/root/directory"
    <Directory /path/to/root/directory>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine On
        Options +FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>

    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE store2
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store
</VirtualHost>
```

And my new base urls are subdomain1.company.com/corporate/ and subdomain2.company.com/corporate/
Obviously, I did something wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated....

Comment: Did you change the URL in the Magento settings (in the admin panel -> **System -> Configuration -> GENERAL -> Web**) and add `RewriteBase /corporate/` to **.htaccess** in Magento main directory?

Comment: base urls are set (domain1.company.com/corporate/ and domain2.company.com/corporate/).
I didn't set any RewriteBase in .htaccess. I'll try that

Comment: RewriteBase did the trick. @michael feel free to write a real answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving Magento installation from localhost to sub-directory in server root?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67745/moving-magento-installation-from-localhost-to-sub-directory-in-server-root)

Comment: No it's not. We just needed to display /corporate/ in the url, but there is no "corporate" subdirectory in file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check/do 2 things:

1. To change the URL in the Magento settings (in the admin panel -> **System -> Configuration -> GENERAL -> Web**).
2. To add `RewriteBase /corporate/` to the **.htaccess** in the Magento main directory (after `RewriteEngine on`).